# Can't get any Javascript file working properly in blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

relatively new to blazor..

I have been using MVC, and webforms but made a dive into blazor and .net core...

What a pain it has been so far from start to finish... Anyway my issue...

```
I am trying to follow this codepen, typewriter text `https://codepen.io/hckkiu/pen/KKzgEMr`
```

Very easy to implement anywhere but blazor... So i have my CSS and javascript file loading correctly but the output is never there..

[image]

Can anyone tell me why its not loading / blazor / c#

The javascript is blinking but no text continuation.

```
<div class='containers'>
    <div class="bodys">
        <p class='typewriter'>
            I'm a
            <span class='typewriter-text' data-text='[ "photographer. ", "designer. ", "developer. " ]'></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    typing(0, $('.typewriter-text').data('text'));

    function typing(index, text) {

        var textIndex = 1;

        var tmp = setInterval(function () {
            if (textIndex < text[index].length + 1) {
                $('.typewriter-text').text(text[index].substr(0, textIndex));
                textIndex++;
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () { deleting(index, text) }, 2000);
                clearInterval(tmp);
            }

        }, 150);

    }

    function deleting(index, text) {

        var textIndex = text[index].length;

        var tmp = setInterval(function () {

            if (textIndex + 1 > 0) {
                $('.typewriter-text').text(text[index].substr(0, textIndex));
                textIndex--;
            } else {
                index++;
                if (index == text.length) { index = 0; }
                typing(index, text);
                clearInterval(tmp);
            }

        }, 150)

    }

});
```

CSS

```
bodys {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
}

.containers {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.typewriter {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: block;
}

.typewriter-text {
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: red;
    border-right: solid #ffe509 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    animation: cursor 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes cursor {
    from {
        border-color: #ffe509;
    }

    to {
        border-color: transparent;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .typewriter {
        font-size: 35px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .typewriter {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

glad to see you are trying out Blazor!

The first lesson should be - Don't try to do everything in JavaScript. Take what you want to do and translate it to Blazor. Using JS libraries and components is an advanced topic - start with plain C# Blazor - [Blazor University](https://blazor-university.com/) is a good resource.

Here is a working repl : https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GOvEwjOY58lmz0ao15

and the code for that - there is no JavaScript required for this in Blazor.

*Note: in the real world you would make this implement IDisposable and use a cancellation token to cancel the long running Task*

```html
    <div class='container'>
      <p class='typewriter'>I'm a 
      <span class='typewriter-text'>@typewriterText</span>
      </p>
    </div>
```

```cs
    @code {
        string[] jobs = { "photographer. ", "designer. ", "developer. " };
        string typewriterText;
        Task worker;
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            worker = Typewriter();
        }
        async Task Typewriter()
        {
            var index = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                var textIndex = 1;
    
                while( textIndex < jobs[ index ].Length + 1 ) 
                {
                  typewriterText = jobs[ index ].Substring( 0, textIndex );
                  textIndex++;
                  StateHasChanged();
                  await Task.Delay(150);
                };
                
                StateHasChanged();
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                
                textIndex = jobs[ index ].Length;
                
                while ( textIndex + 1 > 0 ) 
                {
                    typewriterText = jobs[ index ].Substring( 0, textIndex );
                    textIndex--;
                    StateHasChanged();
                    await Task.Delay(150);
                };
    
                index++;
                if ( index == jobs.Length ) 
                { 
                    index = 0; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mister Magoo. I never thought about doing it in code... Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to call the javascript after your component/page is rendered, `$(document).ready` will not help in this case as the component might be rendered after the page load.

See below example to call the javascript that will then do the functionality that you want:

In your component:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;

// or

[Inject] protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("startTyping");
    }
}
```

Javascript file:

```js
window.startTyping = () => {
    typing(0, $('.typewriter-text').data('text'));
    // other js code here
}
```

See here for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Umair i tried your version but i get errors in my javascript. Could you post how my javascript file should look. Maybe i have done this wrong after imputting the window.startTyping ... I also got interop error saying window is not defined